# How do I get the base map for OpenWeatherMap API 1.0?

Tags: openweathermap

Here is their 1.0 documentation: https://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps.

Since I'm using their free plan, I'm looking to build a simple program to render the weather map overlaid with a given layer. I'm able to get the layers, but I'm not sure how to get the base map.

Here is an example request I'm using to get the temperature layer:

`curl --location --request GET 'https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/0/0/0.png?appid={APPID}'`

I've looked through their documentation, but I've only found a dead link to "Satellite base map for weather layers", which seems exactly what I need.

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention they have a 2.0 weather map, but that requires a subscription. This one doesn't.